# Python Machine learning labels and features

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Given a dataset with 10,000 observations and 50 features plus one label, what would be the dimensions of X_train, y_train, X_test, and y_test, Assuming a train/test split of 75%/25%? Should it be

```
X_train:(2500, 50)
y_train: (2500, )
X_test: (7500, 50)
y_test: (7500, )
```

or

```
X_train: (7500, 50)
y_train: (7500, )
X_test: (2500, 50)
y_test: (2500, )
```

Answer (score 3):

You can see for yourself with [`train_test_split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) from `sklearn`:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

n = 10000
p = 50
X = np.random.random((n,p))
y = np.random.randint(0,2,n)

test = 0.25
d = {}
d["X_train"], d["X_test"], d["y_train"], d["y_test"] = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=test)

for split in d:
    print(split, d[split].shape)

X_train (7500, 50)
X_test (2500, 50)
y_train (7500,)
y_test (2500,)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second one.

> Assuming a train/test split of 75%/25%

It means 75% of the data set is used for training and the rest for testing.
You have 10000 observations, so that's 7500 for training and 2500 for testing.

In general, when we say the `A` / `B` split is `X%` / `Y%`. It means the `A` gets `X%` and `B` gets `Y%`. Always. And also, `X+Y` should be 100.

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer to use as training set of 75% data and rest of them 25% is test set. This usually gives you a good results. (It also depends on your volume of Dataset.)

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, train_size=0.75, random_state=101)
X_train: (7500, 50)
y_train: (7500, )
X_test: (2500, 50)
y_test: (2500, )
```

Consider the inside of train/test split method "train_size" and "test_size". You can set other values on this.

random_state parameter is also for shuffle the dataset parts